# Login in with external tenant, Azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, passport.js

When external azure users try to login, they get:

```
TokenError: AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.
```

When users from same organization as the azure ad client resides in it works.

In the Azure authorization settings "Supported account types" I have the option: "Account in any organization" toggled.

Backend code:

```
passport.use(
  new AzureAdOAuth2Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: `${getBaseUrl()}/api/login/callback`,
      tenant: 'common',
      useCommonEndpoint: true
    }, async (accessToken, refresh_token, params, profile, done) => {...
```

So `tenant` is set to `'common'` to enable multi tenant organization and the setting in Azure is set to allow multi tenants.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Weird issue. I have a customer with a similar symptom you mention.

Finally, after reproducing the problem at my end: the webrequest landing on the DNN page after the redirection of the Azure login creates two requests for "*ExchangeCodeForToken*" (the first one is accepted, but the second is invalid because the code was already processed, as per October 10th update).

I found an updated release package which avoids the second call, that was there since the beginning of the times.

**The new Release v3.0.1** is given below. Can you please double check? I have already installed on my customer website and is now working properly.

```
https://github.com/davidjrh/dnn.azureadprovider/releases/tag/v3.0.1
```

Comment: Is this some .NET package? I'm using NodeJs with passport.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried again in a incognito mode? By the way, tenant parameter is not needed if you enable useCommonEndpoint.

I can login in with external tenant users with a code returned by following [this document](https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2). Can you paste your code here which for login?

Answer (score 0):

Add guest users to the directory
Sign in to the Azure portal as a user who is assigned a limited administrator directory role or the Guest Inviter role.
In the navigation pane, select Azure Active Directory.
Under Manage, select Users.
Select New guest user. ...
Under User name, enter the email address of the external user.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the recent update in Azure AD this behavior is to be expected. As of October 10 Azure AD will no longer accept authorization codes to issue tokens that have already been used. To fix the error try changing your code to request a refresh token that will be passed to /used by additional resources as the refresh tokens can still be reused. I have also linked the official notice in this post for your reference.

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
            Authority = Authority,
            CallbackPath = CallbackPath,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                {
                    var authorizationCode = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                    ClientCredential clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
                    AuthenticationContext authorizationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
                    AuthenticationResult authorizationResult = await authorizationContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(authorizationCode, new Uri(context.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey]), clientCredentials, GraphResourceId);

                    var accessToken = authorizationResult.AccessToken;
                    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => 
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token); 
                    }));
                    .....
                    .....
                    .....
                }
        }
```